# PyQt5 QTreeView show parent directory

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

In PyQt5, I have a QTreeView `tree_view` that has a model called `file_model`. I tried to set the root index by calling `file_model.setRootPath(os.getcwd() + "/sets")` then calling `tree_view.setRootIndex(file_model.index("sets"))`. However, my program only shows the child folders of the directory `sets`, but the parent folder.

A snippet of my code:

```
self.file_model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
self.file_model.setRootPath(getcwd() + "/sets")
self.file_model.setFilter(QDir.AllDirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)

self.tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
self.tree_view.setModel(self.file_model)
self.tree_view.setRootIndex(self.file_model.index("sets"))
```

However, this is shown:

[image]

The problem is that I also want to show the parent directory `sets`. What is a way to do that in PyQt5?

Comment: If you want to use the parent directory as the root, why don't you use that directory as root index?

Comment: hmm... the parent directory is set as the root index. I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: If you want to show the "sets" directory too, you have to set the root to the parent of "sets".